# java glassfish What is the proper way of hosting an application with external images outside of the .war file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, glassfish, wildfly

Hi I searched could not find the answer...

Is this the best way to do this?

```
<h:graphicImage value="file:../../../images/image.jpg"> </h:graphicImage>
```

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 0):

`h:graphicImage` renders an HTML img tag so the same rules apply for requiring that referenced images be available to whomever is viewing your resulting page. `file://` protocol would require that your user have the image file available to them on their machine (or over a mount point).

You probably want to host your images on a webserver (and reference them with `http://` or `https://` or just `://` as well), glassfish or otherwise.

You may find this thread useful [jsf/glassfish hosting static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678668/jsf-glassfish-hosting-static-files). I searched Google thusly: stackoverflow host static files on glassfish